# Avoiding a stack overflow in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, beautifulsoup, overflow

Disclaimer note: I have absolutely no idea about Computer Science and don't have any knowledge about the inner workings of anything that happens behind the scenes. Teaching myself to code using everything there is on the Internet.

Python Version:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit(Intel)] on win32
```

Working on a normal parser, whose main point is to fetch image the full-sized url of an image, save it into a file for downloading later and then move into the next image in line, which is pretty much mandatory due to bad web architecture of the site in question. When I finished the program, I came across an error during the 976th time of execution.

```
  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Upon researching, I found out that the problem in question is due to "Stack overflow". However, currently I have no idea on how to work around without creating any significant performance drops. (Although, that isn't really a problem since I'm just doing it for study.)

Which brings me to my question, how can I fix this problem and where could I learn more about such things, like what is Stack Overflow to begin with?

(The program works fine, stack overflow stops it though)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def somesite_parsing(url):

    connection = requests.get(url)
    html = connection.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # The exception is necessary due to the web architecture.
    # Images that don't have different versions by size have an img tag.
    # Returns "http://www.somesite.net/tag_tag_tag.full.jpg"
    try:
        semi_link = soup.select("html > body > #wrapper > #body > #content > #large > a")
        full_link = semi_link[0].get("href")
        print(full_link)

    except IndexError:
        semi_link = soup.select("html > body > #wrapper > #body > #content > #large > img")
        full_link = semi_link[0].get("src")
        print(full_link)

    # File was created during testing so I switched to appending.
    # Saves link into folder.
    fx = open("list_file.txt", "a")
    fx.write(full_link + "\n")
    fx.close()

    # Fetches the next url.
    # Returns "/id_number"
    next_link = soup.select("html > body > #wrapper > #body > #menu > .smallthumbs > li > a")
    next_link = next_link[0].get("href")
    next_link = "http://www.somesite.net" + next_link
    print(next_link)

    print()
    somesite_parsing(next_link)


somesite_parsing("http://www.somesite.net/1905220")
```

Comment: I am assuming that that last call, `zerochan_parsing`, should actually be `somesite_parsing`?

Comment: Woops, didn't notice that XD

Comment: You are always calling `somesite_parsing` everytime the function gets called again. You need to determine a way to stop calling `somesite_parsing`. So maybe try checking that you are still getting an id_number. If you do not get an id_number then `return` from the function before you call `somesite_parsing` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stack overflow occurs when there are too many nested function calls. This mostly happens when a function continues to call itself endlessly.

In your case, you call `somesite_parsing` inside itself. This eventually leads to a stack overflow.

There are several ways to avoid this. I would recommend having a loop around your parsing.

Change `somesite_parsing` to return the next link, instead of calling itself, and you can do this:

```
next_link = "http://www.somesite.net/1905220"
while next_link:
    next_link = somesite_parsing(next_link)
```

This will allow your to return a [falsy](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html) value from `somesite_parsing` to stop the loop.

Comment: Fixed the problem my shifting everything into a while loop and making url equal to next_link. Could you elaborate perhaps on why this works? It doesn't seem like anything is different.

Comment: The best answer I can give you without getting very technical is the one I already gave: a stack overflow occurs when there are too many nested function calls. Each time a function calls any other function (including itself) before concluding adds another layer of nesting. --- The more technical answer is that the runtime only has room for a set number of stack frames (google it) and frames are added to the stack when a function is called and popped from it when they conclude. If you keep adding frames without popping any you will get and overflow (too many frames).

Comment: What you were originally doing would have been fine in a language with tail call optimization (google it): some languages handle recursion better than others.

Answer (score 0):

A 'while' loop is indeed what you need.

Here is how I would do it, although I've not run the code.

```
import requests
import json

start_url = "http//your_start_url"

def save_data(data):
    """Or however you want to save your data.
     I like .jsonl, see http://jsonlines.org/"""
    data = json.dumps(data)
    fx = open("data_file.jsonl", "a") #see 
    fx.write(data + "\n")
    fx.close()

def get_url(url):
    "This returns something similar to an 'option type'."
    r = requests.get(url)
    return {"success":  r.ok,
            "next_url": parse_your_response_for_next_url(r.text),
            "page":     r.text,
            "url":      url}

##################################


response = get_url(start_url)

while respose["success"]:
    save_data(response)
    response = get_url(response["next_url"])
```

(I'm using a pseudo 'option type' and a jsonl file. But that's just a stylistic decision. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type and http://jsonlines.org/)

Also, if you're making enough requests to reach the maximum recursion depth, it might be nice to store the responses with `@functools.lru_cache` or some disk-backed alternative.